# Stepped off (it/of it)/out (of it) to search the floor

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, writing

An elevator arrived and two police officers stepped off (it/of it) to search the floor.

An elevator arrived and two police officers stepped out (of it) to search the floor.

In the two sentences would it be natural to include "it" or "of it" or do they work fine/better without?

Comment: If _it_ is present, so that what precedes it is a preposition, then standard English requires _out of_ (with _of_) but _off_ (without _of_). _Off of_ does occur in some non-standard varieties; so does prepositional _out_, but in the meaning _through_, not _out of_ (eg _out the door_, _out the window_).

Answer (score 0):

Either construction is fine, but the omission of the implied object (it) makes it a cleaner, more modern sounding sentence.

- An elevator arrived and two police officers stepped off  to search
  the floor.
- An elevator arrived and two police officers stepped out to search the
  floor.

Since you have already stated that the elevator had arrived, you do not need to specify what the police officers were stepping off or out of.  Out and Off are interchangeable here as well.

Comment: I think _out_  would be better, as the elevator is an enclosed space.

Comment: Off works as well, because an elevator is essentially a moving shelf, as well as a moving room.  Both words are commonly used.

Comment: [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=step+out+of+the+elevator%2C+step+off+of+the+elevator&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstep%20out%20of%20the%20elevator%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstep%20off%20of%20the%20elevator%3B%2Cc0) gives clear preference to "step out".

Comment: I would step out of a lift, but step off an escalator. On the other hand I would step off a bus or a train, which are enclosed, and out of a garden bed, which isn't.